# App crashes without showing permission dialog, but works fine when permission is granted manually

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I am relatively new to Android development. I have an app which requires the certain permissions. These are added in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

The app crashes on initial start (both on emulated device and installed apk) but after granting the **CAMERA**, **PHONE** and **STORAGE** permissions manually from the settings of phone, it works fine.

In the `MainActivity`, I have also added permission check like these (in `onCreate`):

```
 // CAMERA permission
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission is not granted
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
       new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
           1);
        }
```

But the app keeps crashing on start without showing the permission dialog. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
Error trace:

[image]

Comment: share your error trace.

Comment: updated with error trace

Comment: it might be a case like you trying to access some thing from internal storage before ask permission. Check in your code that thing. Other wise do one thing ask permission at initially when app is start and then check it.

Comment: @MehulKabaria You're right! Trying to write to storage in ServerInputActivity. In that case I should check and ask permission in that activity?

Comment: In sort Before anything you write or read from internal storage you must have to ask permission.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code, this works for me. Its for camera and storage. Call this method        checkAndRequestPermissions();

```
private void checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
    }


public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //granted
            } else {
                //not granted

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                    showDialogOK(getString(R.string.app_permission_allow),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    switch (which) {
                                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                            checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
                //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                else {
                    showDialogOK(getString(R.string.app_permission_necessary),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    switch (which) {
                                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                            finish();
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                            intent.setData(uri);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            });


                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, not requesting the permission before performing the restricted action was the issue. Can you add some explanation for the steps in code?